# Java question codes on class not executing

Tags: java, swing

Im new to java,

so let say i have a class called A

```
class A {
A {  
//init codes

//why does this code below not works?
if(!jFrame1.isVisible() && !jFrame0.isVisible())
jFrame0.setVisible(true);    
}
```

What i am trying to do is, i have two JFrame, so when ppl press button on jFrame0, jFrame0 will be setVisible(false) and jFrame1 will be opened, so how do i achieve when ppl press X/Close on jFrame1, jFrame0 will be visible back?

Comment: //why does this code not works?  What it shows you ?

Comment: jFrame0 is not visible back, so process is running but nothing is there becuase both jframe is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, if people press a button on `jFrame0`, it is visible (this is true for `jFrame1` as well). So the condition in `if` becomes `false`.

Comment: he means that before you hide jframe0, it is still visible. So your condition is wrong.